# Spectral decomposition of Hermitian positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this always possible to write spectral decomposition of a Hermitian positive definite matrix in terms of unit rank projectors?

Update: I just found this: [About the uniqueness of rank-1 decomposition of a positive-definite Hermitian matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160667/about-the-uniqueness-of-rank-1-decomposition-of-a-positive-definite-hermitian-ma?rq=1),
claiming: "Suppose $T$ is positive-definite Hermitian matrix and I know that it can be expressed by eigen-decomposition as the following sum of rank-1 matrices...", but I am not sure if this claim is correct.

Comment: The lanczos method may be what you're referring to

Comment: No, I am not interested in finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors for an specific matrix. I just want to now whether it is possible in general to write a Hermitian positive definite matrix in terms of unit rank projectors?

Comment: do you not know how krylov methods work?

Comment: Yes, every symmetric matrix (not just positive definite ones) can be decomposed in this way, but the decomposition isn't necessarily unique.  This is a well-known theorem of linear algebra.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thanks. Does this theorem has a name, so I can search for it?

Comment: It's a very simple version of the spectral theorem for self adjoint operators.   I've seen it referred to as "the spectral theorem" or "the orthogonal diagonalization theorem"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectral theorem as it applies to Hermitian matrices can be stated as follows: $T$ is positive definite and Hermitian if and only if there exists a unitary $U$ and real diagonal $D$ such that $T = UDU^*$.

From this version of the spectral theorem, it is easy to obtain the result you're looking for.  In particular, let $u_1,\dots,u_n$ denote the columns of $U$.  By applying [block matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication), we see that
$$
T = UDU^* = \pmatrix{u_1 & \cdots & u_n} \pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_n} \pmatrix{u_1^* \\ \vdots \\ u_n^*}
\\ = \lambda_1 u_1u_1^* + \cdots + \lambda_n u_nu_n^*
$$